# how do I get previous 3 or 5 financial years dynamically.eg 2021-20, 2020-19

Tags: javascript

```
`function getCurrentFinancialYear()
 {
  const thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  const lastYear = thisYear-1;
  return ${lastYear}-${thisYear.toString().slice(-2)};
}
console.log(getCurrentFinancialYear());`
```

This is giving the output only 2020-21

Comment: Its should be `${thisYear}-${lastYear.toString().slice(-2)};`

Comment: how to get last 5 fiscal years in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the year calculation logic in a loop.

I have used `Array.map` to generate the 5 years and used `Array.join` to convert the Array s=as a string.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function getCurrentFinancialYear() {
  const thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  const yearArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((count) => `${thisYear - count}-${(thisYear - count - 1).toString().slice(-2)}`);
  console.log(yearArray);
  return yearArray.join();
}
console.log(getCurrentFinancialYear());
```